# In Linux , I want to search number of files & directories present in a directory

Tags: linux

For example:
I have a directory with project.
In that 3 sub directories.
In that 3 sub directories 1 text file in each.

Now I am using scandir() to find how many files& directive present in that project. But scandir() is only scanning 1 level  mean it is not scanning sub directories how to scan them also.

Comment: Using command line or what?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the command line, you can use find and wc.

To count all files recursively:

```
find . -type f | wc -l
```

To find directory count:

```
find . -type d | wc -l
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

-type f = file

-type d = directory

wc = prints newline, word or byte count which takes a parameter -l to give you line count

If you are referring to using scandir in PHP, you can try something like this:

```
<?php 
function dirToArray($dir) { 

   $result = array(); 

   $cdir = scandir($dir); 
   foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) 
   { 
      if (!in_array($value,array(".",".."))) 
      { 
         if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value)) 
         { 
            $result[$value] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value); 
         } 
         else 
         { 
            $result[] = $value; 
         } 
      } 
   } 

   return $result; 
} 
?>
```

Source: comment #88 http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php